# how to solve phpmyadmin does'nt access in localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error

MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Contact your hosting company

Answer (score 0):

if you use xampp you should turn on the mysql and apache